# Not using optional argument makes environment break

Tags: environments, optional-arguments, filecontents

I'm defining a wrapper environment for `filecontents` so that I can modify its behaviour.

Everything works fine for most of the test cases. For example, I define an environment `testenv` which takes one mandatory argument and writes its value to the console:

```
\newenvironment{testenv}[1]{%
  \typeout{Argument = #1}%
  \filec@ntents{\jobname.pfc}%
}{}
```

so when I call

```
\begin{testenv}{hello}
  hi
\end{testenv}
```

LaTeX prints `Argument = hello` to the console and writes a file called `\jobname.pfc` which contains

```
hi
```

This works for environments without arguments, and with mandatory arguments. For environments with optional arguments it works as long as the optional argument is present, otherwise it fails.

The code below illustrates all the cases. The last one will throw a `Missing \begin{document}` error:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\makeatletter

\newenvironment{testenv}{%
  \filec@ntents{\jobname.pfc}%
}{}
% The environment works without arguments
\begin{testenv}
  hi
\end{testenv}

\renewenvironment{testenv}[1]{%
  \typeout{Argument = #1}%
  \filec@ntents{\jobname.pfc}%
}{}
% and with mandatory arguments
\begin{testenv}{hello}
  hi
\end{testenv}

\renewenvironment{testenv}[1][abcde]{%
  \typeout{Argument = #1}%
  \filec@ntents{\jobname.pfc}%
}{}
% and it works with optional arguments
% only if the argument is given
\begin{testenv}[hello]
  hi
\end{testenv}

% otherwise it fails :/
\begin{testenv}
  hi
\end{testenv}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

The actual use of the argument is for some text to be typeset after the contents of the environment, so the catcode will not be of much importance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the catcode-régime used by the filecontents-environment is in effect before having your environment process whatsoever argument.

Processing optional arguments is possible under filecontents-catcode-régime as applying that régime does not change the catcode of `[`.

Depending on what you wish to do with the optional argument within your real-life-application, you might need to have it retokenized under normal catcode-régime.
(For a simple `\typeout` this is not necessary.)

This can be done via `\scantokens` from the eTeX-extensions.

If eTeX-extensions are not available, this can be done by unexpanded-writing it to a temporary file and via `\input` (TeX) / `\@@input` (LaTeX2e) making (La)TeX read/tokenize that temporary file.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\setcatcodesoffilecontents{%
  \let\do\@makeother\dospecials
  %
  \count0=128\relax
  \loop %
    \catcode\count0=11\relax
    \advance\count0 by 1\relax
  \ifnum\count0<256 %
  \repeat 
  %
  \catcode`\^^L\active
  \catcode`\^^I\active
  \catcode`\^^M\active
}%
\newenvironment{testenv}{%
  \begingroup
  \setcatcodesoffilecontents
  \innertestenv
}{}%
\newcommand\innertestenv[1][abcde]{%
  \endgroup
  \typeout{Argument = #1}%
  \@tempswatrue   %<-As file-preamble write the phrase
                  %   %% LaTeX2e file `\jobname.pfc'
                  %   %% generated by the `testenv' environment
                  %   %% from source `test' on 2018/06/30.
  %\@tempswafalse  %<-Don't write a file-preamble.
  \filec@ntents{\jobname.pfc}%
}%


% With optional argument:
%
%\begin{testenv}[hello]
%  hi
%\end{testenv}

% Without optional argument:
%
\begin{testenv}
  hi
\end{testenv}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ooh, neat. Thanks Ulrich :) This time the optional argument just some bunch of text, so the catcode doesn't matter much. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 4):

Collecting material using `filecontents` or similar uses verbatim approaches. That means that any tokenization can (and here will) cause issues. The problem you see is that when looking for an optional `[`, TeX tokenizes up to and including the `h`. In particular, this means the line end has 'vanished'. Collecting up tokens relies on grabbing up to the line end (`^^M`), so here we 'loose' the `h`, which triggers `\everypar` and thus the error.

Something similar comes up in `beamer`, where extra steps are taken to 'make safe' the first token after the start of a line. However, that is at best somewhat fragile and I would not rely on it.

Comment: Thanks Joseph :) I see, the `^^M` is consumed, and `filecontents`'s verbatim processor requires the `^^M` to start doing its thing. Is there a way to make this work that justifies the effort or should I just make that argument mandatory?